# Reopen room database after restore of db file

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room

How do I correctly reopen database after DB file is restored? I am opening it in AppModule like this:

```
@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideDb(app: Application): FastcountDb {
    val db: FastcountDb = Room.databaseBuilder(app, FastcountDb::class.java, AppConfig.DB_NAME + ".db")
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .setJournalMode(RoomDatabase.JournalMode.TRUNCATE)
            .build()

    return db
}
```

when I backup or restore the DB file I just call RoomDatabase.close() copy db file and I need to reopen the DB. Is there any way how to trigger the provideDb(app: Application) again ?